# Creating df from either not in either list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'all_tokens': ['BTC', 'WETH', 'SOL', 'sBTC', 'sWETH', 'sSOL', 'AVAX', 'LTC', 'ETC'],
                   'amount': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]})
```

Output:

```
  all_tokens  amount
0        BTC      10
1       WETH      20
2        SOL      30
3       sBTC      40
4      sWETH      50
5       sSOL      60
6       AVAX      70
7        LTC      80
8        ETC      90
```

And the following lists:

```
base_tokens = ['BTC', 'WETH', 'SOL']
other_tokens = ['sBTC', 'sWETH', 'sSOL']
```

I want to create a `new_df` only with values in the `'all_tokens'` column in the `df` that **are not in** either list.

Expected output:

```
  new_tokens
0       AVAX
1        LTC
2        ETC
```

I have tried:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'new_tokens': df['all_tokens'].loc[(~df['all_tokens'].isin(base_tokens)) & (~df['all_tokens'].isin(other_tokens))]})
```

No success. My result is a `new_df` with all tokens from both lists.

Comment: Why don't you combine those lists to one?

Comment: Because I need them separately for another piece of my code.

Comment: So create a new list and keep two other lists. Where is the problem?

Comment: I am getting the expected result when I run your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Combine two list and convert them to set 
set_all = set(base_tokens + other_tokens)

res = df.loc[~df['all_tokens'].isin(set_all), 'all_tokens'].to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)

print(res)
```

Output:

```
  all_tokens
0       AVAX
1        LTC
2        ETC
```